# Slug generator doesn't generate slug for tablecontent

Tags: python, django, database, pipeline

I don't know why the slug generator does not generate a slug for the items in my table. It works perfectly if I save the data with the .save() command. But it does not work with a pipeline which does not use Django related commands.

I use a PostgreSQL database.

Model:

```
    class WhiskyContent(models.Model):
        products = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        price = models.FloatField(default=20)
        date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        picture = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        site = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        product_link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        shipping = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.products
    
        objects = models.Manager
    
    
    def product_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if not instance.slug:
            instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)
    
    
    pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_receiver, sender=WhiskyContent)
```

Pipeline into database:

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import logging

class Frankbrauer360Pipeline(object):


def __init__(self):
    self.create_connection()

def create_connection(self,):
    hostname = 'localhost'
    username = 'postgres'
    password = 'Whisky#123!'
    database = 'Items'
    x = 1
    try:
        if (x == 1):
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        sys.exit()
    finally:
        logging.info('Connection opened successfully.')

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
            insert into homepage_whiskycontent(products, price, picture, site, product_link, shipping, date)
            values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
            ''', [
                    item['products'],
                    item['price'],
                    item['picture'],
                    item['site'],
                    item['product_link'],
                    item['shipping'],
                    item['date'],
             #      item["slug"],
    ])
    self.connection.commit()
    return item

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.connection.close()
```

Slug generator:

```
import random
import string
from django.utils.text import slugify


def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None): 

if new_slug is not None:
    slug = new_slug
else:
    slug = slugify(instance.products)

Klass = instance.__class__
qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
if qs_exists:
    new_slug = "{slug}-{randstr}".format(
                slug=slug,
                randstr=random_string_generator(size=4)
            )
    return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
return slug
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work if you're inserting data without using Django?

Comment: I had the problem that i wasn't able to import the model in the pipeline. But now I implemented scrapy to Django and it works pretty well :)

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with your code here but the signal will only fire if you call django's .save() method.